# which file extensions are dedicated to an application in OSX

Tags: macos, file-extension

Is there a way to find out which file extensions are dedicated to an app?I don't mean dedicating in with "always open file with app" from finder dialog. I mean the other way round. Start with the app and find out which extensions are dedicated to it.
Thanks for a hint.

Comment: Not sure SO is the right place for this question, maybe [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [ask-different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate. But you can get which file type an app does declare to accept in its *info.plist* (Show Package Contents > Contents > info.plist) search for *CFBundleTypeName* or *CFBundleTypeExtensions* keys. Though, I don't know where the os stores the currently "set as default"  app.